# Reaction Roles (JS)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I've been making a Discord Bot for myself and don't get me wrong, I'm still in the learning phase of JS but I know a tiny bit to get me started. I've been making a Reaction Role Command and just wondering if there's a way to make it so that you can only react to 1 thing at a time.

For example, I have a color selector but only want members to choose 1 at a time and if they react to a different color it unreacts to the first color they chose

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactioncolor',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
        const channel = '865154605356285962';
        const redTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Red");
        const orangeTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Orange");
        const yellowTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Yellow");
        const blueTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Blue");
 
        const redTeamEmoji = '';
        const orangeTeamEmoji = '';
        const yellowTeamEmoji = '';
        const blueTeamEmoji = '';
 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Choose your colour!')
            .setDescription('\n\n'
                + `${redTeamEmoji} ➜ <@&865163260500377602>\n`
                + `${orangeTeamEmoji} ➜ <@&865163175091503104>\n`
                + `${yellowTeamEmoji} ➜ <@&865163103469961226>\n`
                + `${blueTeamEmoji} ➜ <@&866988159162515527>\n`);
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(redTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(orangeTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(yellowTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(blueTeamEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === redTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(redTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === orangeTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(orangeTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(blueTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === redTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(redTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === orangeTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(orangeTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(blueTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
 
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should take a look at discord.js V13's [Select Menus](https://v13-prep.discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html) they would make your life a lot easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can remove user's older reaction if they click on a new one.

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {

    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

    // ...

    reaction.message.reactions.cache.forEach((otherReaction) => {
        if (reaction.emoji.name == otherReaction.emoji.name) return;
        if (otherReaction.users.cache.some(otherUser => user.id == otherUser.id)) {
            otherReaction.users.remove(user);
        }
    });

    // ...

}
```

Be aware that this only works supposing that the `.cache`s are up to date. Otherwise you would need to fetch them.

But as @Viriato suggested, [Select Menus](https://v13-prep.discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html) are definitely the best solution.

Comment: The problem is `reaction` and `otherReaction` are `MessageReaction` objects and you can't compare objects in JS. You can check the reaction emoji though, so it should be `reaction.emoji === otherReaction.emoji`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros But `reaction.emoji` is also an object of [`ReactionEmoji`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionEmoji). Also could you explain why it works this way? I wasn't comfortable writing it like this, but it behaves as expected. So why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I meant `reaction.emoji.name === otherReaction.emoji.name`.  Do you mean that `reaction == otherReaction` works as expected?

Comment: Yep, it skips one of the four reactions. I will update my answer and compare users by their `User.id` and reactions by `ReactionEmoji.name` as you suggested. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Hmm, I wonder, if you print the reactions to the console, there is `<ref *2>` prepended to the object. If they are references, couldn't they be pointing to the same memory? And this way it works, cuz it compares the memory addresses?